# Can VB6 Call a C# COM object Overloaded Method

Tags: c#, vb6

I have a C# COM object with two public methods.

1. `SendMessage()`
2. `SendMessage(int priority)`

I am trying to call these methods from a VB6 project, but intellisense shows only the method without the priority. If I try entering a priority anyway I get a compile error, "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment".

Am I just doing something wrong, or do I need to change the C# dll?

Comment: There's no overloading in VB6 so you can't have multiple functions with the same name.

Comment: @MethodMan what more does this question need? It seems clear, to the point, and an issue the querent was having.

Comment: I also don't see why it was closed. The question is perfectly clearly formulated. There are no "debugging details" required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> or do I need to change the C# dll

If you can, then that would be for the better, as COM does not support overloading, so it is best avoided with COM-visible interfaces.

There *should* be a method in the COM interface that is something like `SendMessage_2(int priority)` bound to your `SendMessage(int priority)` though.